# Summing column values based on multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe which for simplicity is as follows;

```
                      Values    
01-01-2010 Belgium    1    
           Belgium    7
           UK         3 
           UK         4
           UK         2
           France     1
           France     3
02-01-2010 Belgium    4
           UK         7
           UK         10
           UK         2
           France     4
```

I need to try and sum the value for each country for each day.
The actual dataframe has approx 10 years of data and 40 countries.

Is there any simple way of using the resample() function to do this?
I can't seem to get one working with the multiindex. I could perhaps convert the countries back to a column?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` your indices by specifying the levels

```
df2 = df.groupby(level=[0,1])['Values'].sum()
print(df2)
01-01-2010   Belgium       8
             France        4
             UK            9
02-01-2010   Belgium       4
             France        4
             UK           19
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'm actually now getting this error.. `ValueError: level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex`. Perhaps my columns aren't indexed correctly?

Comment: @spcol `print(df.index)`  paste the output here

Comment: `print(df.index)` `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=66766, step=1)`

Comment: @spcol looks like you only have a single index, what does `print(df.columns)` yield ?

Comment: I've gone for this;

`df = df.groupby(['Time','From Country']).agg({'Value': 'sum'})`

which afterwards yields a MultiIndex for df2. So I think this will do the job!

Comment: `print(df.columns)` just yields the column names.. no sign of the index headers.

Comment: have accepted your answer as I think the issue was my indexing to begin with. This would have worked if the index was correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, think this will work if I allow the index to be columns first;

```
sum_df = df.groupby(['Time','From Country']).agg({'Value': 'sum'})
```